# Auto-selecting <canvas> on browser?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, processing.js

I am currently running into some issues with a canvas. When loading a Processing.js sketch it requires the user to click on the canvas once in order for it to be selected. Are there any workarounds for auto selection on page load. I have been looking at autofocus, but I was hoping for a fix that supports cross-browser implementation. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!!!

Update!!! E.g of the code I am running... (I have left void setup and void draw blank)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
/* Removes focus outline from canvas */
canvas:focus{outline:none;} 
</style>

<script src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
</script> 

<!-- This is the processing canvas------------------------- -->
<script src="processing.js"></script>
<script type="text/processing" data-processing-target="myCanvas">

PShape boy;
PShape girl;

void setup(){......}
void draw(){......}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Update!

This is the error I am receiving when I attempt markE's approach.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Can you show how you're loading your sketch? Code helps us answer your question

Comment: @jasonscript I have added an example of the code I am running, any help would be appreciated... :-)

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue? Canvas has to be clicked once before it can be interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

I think the script is running before the `canvas` element is added to your page. Since you're using jQuery, you could try wrapping it in a `document.ready()` function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    PShape boy;
    PShape girl;

    void setup(){......}
    void draw(){......}
});
```

Comment: I have tried this, adding a canvas id click when the document is ready, but couldn't get it to work...

Answer (score -1):

By default the canvas element is not assigned a tabindex.  Therefore it cannot receive focus:

To get focus you can set a tabindex on the canvas.

```
// get a reference to the canvas
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');

// set canvas to be a tab stop (necessary to get events)
canvas.setAttribute('tabindex','0');

// set focus to the canvas so keystrokes are immediately handled
canvas.focus();
```

Comment: Hey markE I tried this option and It's not working for me. I have updated my question with a code sample so things are clearer. Your help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Now that you've posted your code, you would want to get a canvas reference like this:  `var canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');`

Comment: Hey markE I have tried this and it is still not working. I've updated the question with a screenshot of the error I am getting.